# vim automatically indent comma exception

Tags: vim, indentation

VIM automatically indent the following code, `.b = 2` line indentation looks very bad.

```
struct foo test(void) { 
    return (struct foo) {
           .a = 1,
                .b = 2,
    };
}
```

How can I change indentation settings so it would look like this?

```
struct foo test(void) {
    return (struct foo) {
         .a = 1,
         .b = 2,
    };
}
```

Comment: You can keep the cursor on bracket near too and press `=I{`.

Comment: Just to be curious, what language is it? Must be something like java or c#, but i don't know them. Btw, it may be useful to add it (the language) as a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `cinoptions` :

```
:set cino+=J1
```

After that indent it with the command **`=`** (*ex: indent all the file **`gg=G`***)